# extract code from jmeter or similar DSL code

Tags: java

I am writing an application that looks very similar to jmeter, except 'actions' are  different.  How can I extract the basic code (setting up nodes and allowing user to add new nodes etc) from jmeter?

Comment: Download the source and search inside? We wont do it for you!

Comment: i didn't mean to ask for code. i was wondering if there is a template or generic approach for it.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is using GUI widget toolkit Java's Swing. You can check example of [Tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) and add [drag and drop](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_Swing/1550__Java_Swing_Drag_Drop.htm) abilities and [add/remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928839/adding-and-removing-nodes-from-a-jtree) items.