# Binary sort tree about JTree

Tags: java, swing, binary-search-tree, jtree

When deleting one node with a child (tree), I don't know how to set the child of a node as the child of the parent of the node and then remove the node in the `JTree`.

Just like:

```
node.getChildNode().setParent(node.getParent)
node = null
```

When I tried to use:

```
node.removeFromParent()
```

It will remove this node including its subtrees directly.
What's more, I want to know how to expand a path that is from the root to a specific node. I tried some methods online, however, after calling the method like `jtree.updateUI()` and `model.reload()`, UI didn't change.

Comment: [Adding and removing nodes from a JTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928839/adding-and-removing-nodes-from-a-jtree)

Comment: [How to Use Trees](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)